# Is recommended to release CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame?

Tags: opencv, android, opencv3.1

I am working in an Android app that uses `JavaCameraView`. So in my activity I implement `CvCameraViewListener2`.

My implementation of `onCameraFrame()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    return bs.process(frame);
}
```

And my question is: would it be good if I release `frame` as I am not using it anymore? So to do something like this:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat result = bs.process(frame);
    frame.release();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **don't have** to release the `inputFrame` matrix but you have to **be careful** with your return matrix.

**Explanation:**

`onCameraFrame()` callback [is called](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android%2BCameraBridgeViewBase.java#L392) in `deliverAndDrawFrame()` method from `CameraBridgeViewBase`:

```
protected void deliverAndDrawFrame(CvCameraViewFrame frame) {
    Mat modified;
    if (mListener != null) {
        modified = mListener.onCameraFrame(frame);
    } else {
        modified = frame.rgba();
    }
    ...
}
```

`deliverAndDrawFrame()` method [is called](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android+JavaCameraView.java#L352) in the `CameraWorker` from `JavaCameraView`:

```
...
if (!mStopThread && hasFrame) {
    if (!mFrameChain[1 - mChainIdx].empty())
        deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[1 - mChainIdx]);
}
...
```

`mCameraFrame` is an array of `JavaCameraFrame` type. If you look at [this class](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android+JavaCameraView.java#L298) you can see where the matrix comes from:

```
@Override
public Mat gray() {
    return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
}

@Override
public Mat rgba() {
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
    return mRgba;
}
```

#### In case of `gray()`:

`mYuvFrameData` is a Mat that [is reused](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android+JavaCameraView.java#L290) with each new frame -> you don't have to release it.

#### In case of `rgba()`:

`mYuvFrameData` is converted to `mRgba`. `mRgba` is a class member initialized in the constructor and reused each time.
The `cvtColor()` method uses `create()` method to [allocate space](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L8684) in the dst matrix. This method works as follow ([JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#create(int,%20int,%20int))):

- If the current array shape and the type match the new ones, **return immediately**.
- Otherwise, **de-reference the previous data by calling "Mat.release"**.
- ...

So, neither have you to release in this case.

#### Return matrix

If we look again the code of `deliverAndDrawFrame()` method, we can see how our return matrix is processed:

```
...
modified = mListener.onCameraFrame(frame);
...
```

Our return matrix is directly assigned, but the previous one is **not released**.

So we have two options:

1. Reuse our return matrix converting it to a class member (recommended).
2. Modify the `CameraBridgeViewBase` [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android%2BCameraBridgeViewBase.java#L400), adding `modified.release()`:

**Option 1** (following your example):

```
...

private Mat processedFrame;

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    processedFrame = new Mat();
    ...
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();  
    Mat result = bs.process(frame);   
    result.copyTo(processedFrame);
    result.release(); 
    return processedFrame;
}
```

**Option 2**:

```
protected void deliverAndDrawFrame(CvCameraViewFrame frame) {
    ...
    boolean bmpValid = true;
    if (modified != null) {
        try {
            Utils.matToBitmap(modified, mCacheBitmap);
            modified.release(); // Add this line
            ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Could you provide an example of how to reuse the return matrix?

Comment: Actually, if I don't release the return matrix as you say, I get this error after 5 minutes running the app: `OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 921600 bytes) in void* cv::OutOfMemoryError(size_t) ... error: (-215) u != 0 in function void cv::Mat::create`. Thank you again.